# Command line processing in Racket contains embedded void

Tags: command-line, scheme, racket

What about command-line processing in racket do I not understand?
For example, I just want to process the first argument as foo.html.
From the command-line I run it as:

```
racket cmd.rkt foo.html
```

Unfortunately that just returns:

```
foo.html'#(#<void>)
```

Here's the code for cmd.rkt:

```
(for/vector ([i (current-command-line-arguments)])
    (display i))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for/vector` isn't called that because it iterates over vectors, it's called that because it accumulates the results of its body expression into a vector. So for each commandline argument it evaluates the `display` call, which prints the argument and returns `#<void>`, and accumulates the result into a vector of void values.

Use `for` instead and the problem will go away.

Comment: Ahh, got it. That makes much more sense.

Comment: Panda, you might have meant to write `(for ([i (in-vector (current-command-line-arguments))]) ....`. Using an explicit sequence such as `in-vector`, `in-list`, and so on is optional. Including it allows somewhat more-specific and faster code to be generated. Anyway, as jacobm explained, with the various `for/<something>` forms, `<something>` is what is _returned_. All of these are wrappers (conceptually) around `for/fold`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see what the code is doing. With this command...

```
racket cmd.rkt foo.html
```

... You're telling the interpreter: run `cmd.rkt` and pass a single parameter, the string `"foo.html"`.

In the script, this code...

```
(for/vector ([i (current-command-line-arguments)])
    (display i))
```

...Is iterating over the command line arguments (a single one in the example), displaying each one in turn. Do notice that [`display`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._display%29%29) returns `#<void>` as its value, and [`for/vector`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html#%28part._for_vector_and_for__vector%29) creates a vector with all the returned values in the iteration, so naturally this is the output:

```
foo.html'#(#<void>)
```

The first part, `foo.html` is the result of displaying the single command line argument that was passed. The second part, `'#(#<void>)` is a vector with a single element, `#<void>`, which as mentioned before, is the result of calling `display`.

Finally, as has been mentioned in the other answers: if you only intended to *print* all of the received command line arguments, then avoid using `for/vector` - you don't want to create a new vector, only traverse and print the arguments and a simple [`for`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html#%28part._for_and_for_%29) will suffice. This should work, and includes @GregHendershott's recommended optimization regarding the use of [`in-vector`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-vector%29%29):

```
(for ([i (in-vector (current-command-line-arguments))])
    (display i))
```

Comment: The for definitely suffices for what I was trying to do - thanks for the deeper explanation.